# how to hover a span inside a a tag

Tags: html, css

I have an a tag and inside the a tag is a span with a class called "arrow". 
I have a hover style on the a tag which turns the text blue. I also want the arrow to turn blue when the a tag is hovered over.

```
<div id="results" class="center">
    <div class='link'>
        <a href="#">How to use SimplyBuilt support</a>
        <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this but didn't work.

```
// This works
#results .link a:hover {
    color: #0098ff;
}

//This does not
#results .link .arrow a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this:

```
<div id="results" class="center">
    <div class='link'>
        <a href="#">How to use SimplyBuilt support</a>
        <span class="arrow"></span> <!-- this span is NOT inside the a.href -->
    </div>
</div>
```

You would need to target `.link a:hover + .arrow`

However, if the `span` is, in fact, inside the link the HTML would be

```
<div id="results" class="center">
    <div class='link'>
        <a href="#">How to use SimplyBuilt support
        <span class="arrow"></span> <!-- this span IS inside the a.href -->
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You would target `.link a:hover .arrow`

Answer (score 0):

To select something that is alongside the current item, use `+`

```
#results .link a:hover+.arrow
```

This should do it.

Comment: The arrow is not inside the a as you can see from my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
#results .link a:hover span{
   /* your style */
}
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the `a:hover` be before the `.arrow`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does the trick:

```
#results .link a:hover .arrow {
  background-color: red; }
```

Comment: The html is in the post. What more html would you need than that ??